# GXT 2.X to 4.0.2 migration issues

Tags: java-8, gwt, gxt

We used to have GWT 2.4 & GXT 2.2.5 and we are migrating to GWT 2.8.1.

Now I am using GWT 2.8 with gxt 2.2.5 and Jdk 1.8.0_291, even when upgrading gxt-2.3.1a-gwt22 I still get this error when maven is building I got this error

```
jar:file:/war/WEB-INF/lib/gxt-2.3.1a-gwt22.jar!/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/widget/form/ListField.java' > Line 322: The method append(boolean) is ambiguous for the type StringBuffer
```

After searching I thought it is imposible to resolve it, I don't have the right to edit the dependency.

So I decided to upgrade gxt to 4.0.2, am I right?

but when I did all the app broke, most of Types don't exist anymore and the migration is not well documented on sencha website, they provide a unique page that doesn't help.

Do you have  a tutorial or a guide that helps? or maybe a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Moving from GXT 2.x to 4.0.2 will create a lot of work. Take a look here:

[Sencha GXT 2.x to 4.x Migration Guide](https://docs-devel.sencha.com/gxt/4.x/guides/getting_started/migration/Migration2to3.html)

To get gxt-2.3.1a working with GWT 2.8.2 or even 2.9.0 (and maybe 2.10.0 - did not check this) you need to fix the bugs. The easiest way would be to
override the class and correct the things that are wrong.

F.e.: Fixing the ListField bug, you have to:

- create a package: 'com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form'
- create a class named 'ListField'
- copy the code from the ListField class into you new class
- fix the problem

I did that in the past and IIRC it was not much work.

Comment: thanks for your response. Do you mean unzip the jar correct the class then compile and zip it again and changing the extension to .jar? or tis there a better way?

Comment: Just create a new java file in your project with the same package and same name and paste the code f. e. of the ListField class. Then add the missing method. IIRC there are a few more things today.